# Why does adding a post to a user in the DB take so long and how can I improve the speed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a C# MVC website with SQL Server and use Entity Framework v6. Users can add a post to the group they are associated with. Instead of just adding it to the database's Post table, I add it to the User's Group's Post like this:

```
...
var addedByUser = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
var group = addedByUser.Group;
group.Posts.Add(newPost);
db.SaveChanges();
```

This one line, `group.Posts.Add(newPost);` takes about 80 seconds to complete. If I just use `db.Posts.Add(newPost);` it only takes a few milliseconds. I have tried disabling change tracking but it didn't make a difference.

**Why does this take so long and what can be done to improve it?** Does it have anything to do with the amount of posts there are for that group in the database?

My database is setup like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }

    ...
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

    ...
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    ...

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always look at the executed SQL statements!

You're triggering lazy loading twice:

```
var group = addedByUser.Group; // Loads Group.
group.Posts ... // Loads Posts
```

It's probably this last statement that takes much time.

So you're fetching large amounts of data while in the end you only need a `Group`'s Id. Assuming some properties to be present you could do it like so:

```
var groupId = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId())
                      .Select(u => u.GroupId).Single();
newPost.GroupId = groupId;
```

Comment: Vastly improved speed, thanks. I don't have access to the GroupId but adding `newPost.Group = group;` then just `db.Posts.Add(newPost);` seems to work fine and only took 38 milliseconds!

Comment: In that case you only fetch some redundant `Group` properties, because you populate the whole entity, but at least the killer-statement `group.Posts` is avoided.

Comment: One more question, it didn't used to take long however now there are 100k+ posts, does that affect the time it took with my original code?

Comment: Just look at how many posts you materialize by `group.Posts`. Fetching the data takes time, but creating CLR objects from the data also takes considerable amounts of time. So, the more records, the more time it takes. Maybe this also merits some scrutiny after proper indexing in the database.